# How can I load a property on a new object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Basically put, I have something along the lines of:

```
public class Product
{
public int ID {Get;Set;}
public string foo {Get;Set;}
public string bar {Get;Set;}
public virtual SubProduct subproduct{get;set;}
public int SubProductID{get;set;}
}

public class SubProduct
{
public int ID {Get;Set;}
public string foo {Get;Set;}
}
```

I have a method that takes a string and does a search through foo -

`var correctproduct = (db.product.SingleOrDefault(x => x.foo == my_string);`

and, if it can find it, I use correctproduct, but, if it doesn't exist (checked via `if correctproduct==null`, I create a new object and perform `.SaveChanges();`.

However, I go straight on to the next part where I interact with subproduct. The part where I create the new object assigned a numerical value to `subproduct`, but, trying to expand, I just get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. The next time it is run, it works perfectly.

I have an idea where I can do a search for subproduct for id and assign the object to the `subproduct` property direct, but, I don't feel this is the best way. I also feel my use of `SingleOrDefault` is just a hack and was wondering if I can have some feedback on the best way of doing this?

Comment: It would be nice if you use real time names like Customer/Product etc in the questions instead of 123 & 456. People will be able to understand your question easily on that context.

Comment: You cannot create Class with names like 123 please update your example so we can focus on the questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code,

```
objectProduct.subProduct = new SubProduct{ ID = id,foo = value };
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I don't want to create a new subproduct, I am assigning the SubProductID an ID of an existing one and I then want to expand SubProduct to load the object.

Comment: you must create object before accessing it. So this the way u have to do it.

Comment: objectProduct.subProduct = new SubProduct{ ID = objectProduct.ID,foo = value };